# Why is the time-in is not working here but the time-out is working?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Why is it the time-in data are the same throughout the data but the time-out is not.
in time-out it referencing the correct row while the time-in not.

here is my sql query

```
SELECT a.emp_id
    ,d.course_code
    ,d.start_time
    ,d.end_time
    ,(
        SELECT TIME
        FROM hris_biometrics_attendance
        WHERE DATE = '2017-06-13'
            AND (TIME <= d.start_time)
            AND emp_id = a.emp_id
            AND floor = d.floor LIMIT 1
        ) AS time_in
    ,(
        SELECT TIME
        FROM hris_biometrics_attendance
        WHERE DATE = '2017-06-13'
            AND (TIME >= d.end_time)
            AND emp_id = a.emp_id
            AND floor = d.floor LIMIT 1
        ) AS time_out
FROM hris_ftl_final_courses a
    ,hris_ftl_final_courses_details d;
```

Here is my database output:

```
emp_id | course_code | start_time | end_time | time_in | time_out 
   1   | COURSE1     | 08:00:00   | 09:00:00 | 7:59:33 | 09:05:00
   1   | COURSE2     | 10:00:00   | 12:00:00 | 7:59:33 | 12:06:00
   1   | COURSE3     | 13:30:00   | 15:00:00 | 7:59:33 | null
```

i want the time-in is less than the start_time or equal to the start_time.
My sql query is not working.

I am using heidisql. mariadb

can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Without an `ORDER BY`, the Optimizer is free deliver the rows in any order it desires.  `LIMIT 1` gives you the first of this unpredictably-ordered list.

Add `ORDER BY TIME ASC` to one subquery, `ORDER BY TIME DESC` to the other.